# Can't access patron data using Patreon Api

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, patreon

Главный вопрос таков. Я делаю дискорд бота, который получает все мейлы моих патронов на патреоне, но я пока могу только получать их id и то кое-как, и он мне выдает огромный массив информации, который еще часа 3 разбирать. Кто-то сталкивался с использованием patreon api на с#?

[https://www.patreon.com/api/oauth2/v2/identity?fields[user]=about,created,email](https://www.patreon.com/api/oauth2/v2/identity?fields%5Buser%5D=about,created,email) - этот код написан в -
https://docs.patreon.com/#get-api-oauth2-v2-identity документации апишки, но никакой информации по-поводу, откуда брать этот [user] и как его получить нет. Postman выдает такую ошибку при вводе:

```
 "code": 1,
        "code_name": "Bad Request",
        "detail": "Error trying to decode a non urlencoded string. Found invalid characters: {']', '['} in the string: 'fields[current-user]=about,created,email'. Please ensure the request/response body is x-www-form-urlencoded.",
```

My whole code (c#) is -

```
myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", "Bearer *my token here*");
                                HttpResponseMessage response = await myClient.GetAsync("https://www.patreon.com/api/oauth2/v2/fields[user]=about,created,email");
```

string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
Console.WriteLine(response);`

Comment: А где вы в API документации увидели адрес `/api/oauth2/v2/fields[user]=about,created,email`? Я лично вижу `/api/oauth2/v2/identity?fields[user]=about,created,email`. Посмотрите хотяб пример сбоку, там прям полноценная ссылка с результатом, который она выдаст.

Comment: Я проверил эти две ссылки и они не выводят той информации, которую мне надо. Я начал использовать https://docs.patreon.com/#get-api-oauth2-v2-campaigns-campaign_id вот эту доку используя ссылку - https://www.patreon.com/api/oauth2/v2/campaigns/6353206/members?include=currently_entitled_tiers,address&fields[member]=full_name, которая тоже выдавала ошибку, пока я не убрал некоторые элементы в хвосте и осталась https://www.patreon.com/api/oauth2/v2/campaigns/6353206/members?include=currently_entitled_tiers, которая идеально работает. Остается вопрос, как заставить работать ВСЮ ссылку, а не часть.

Comment: я получаю - 
{
            "attributes": {},
            "id": "0b633224-c36d-4158-a861-cf36aaf8c812",
            "relationships": {
                "address": {
                    "data": null
                },
                "currently_entitled_tiers": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": "6853734",
                            "type": "tier"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "type": "member"

но вопрос, как из "id" получить инфу по данному мемберу?

Comment: а он точно должен отдавать емейлы польщователей? Это выглядит как вопрос безопасности, раздавать емейлы своих юзеров через свой же АПИ

Comment: Персональные данные никто без личного согласия юзера не шарит. Иначе либо засмеют, либо засудят, либо и то и другое.

Comment: да, бот на python делает это, но это горомный костыль тогда будет запускать python скрипт на debian через c#